# SQL: How to store and select person who available on the same date range

Tags: mysql, sql

From the image below, I want to...

1.Find solution to store unavailable date of each users.
2.I want to select users who available on specify date range.

Red = Unavailable,White = Available.

Example: I will have a training course on day 3 to 4, so i should get Mr.A and Mr.C as my query result.

[image]

Comment: please add more description

Comment: `unavailable date of each users` - What describes unavailable/available  date here? color?

Comment: You should add table definitions and sample data. Or is it a homework?

Comment: Poor table design. Have one row per date instead.

Comment: @chiragpatel Thank you, I want to know how to store this kind of data,e.g. Name as column instead of Name as row.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Thank you,Red = unavailable, White = available.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you, I will do.

Comment: Try to do some basic design yourself - you can learn more that way. You will have one table with people and one table associating dates with people.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Thanks again.

Comment: @jarlh There's no suggestion that the OP intended the above to be a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have a table like this:

```
Create table course_calendar (
date date not null,
course_id int not null,
tutor_id int default null,
primary key (date, course_id)
) engine = innodb;

create table tutor_calendar (
date date not null,
tutor_id int not null,
available enum('Y','N') default 'N',
Primary key (date, tutor_id)
) engine = innodb;
```

Then you would need to join the two tables and see which course_calendar has tutor_id is null 
and see which tutor_calendar has tutor_id and available='Y' for the same dates.

Comment: Thanks for the idea i will try it now.

Comment: @NoppNLearner Don't store a flag for availability. Just store the date ranges for which a tutor is unavailable - start_date and end_date